# How do you change the search location of the Music Lens?

Tags: unity, music, 11.10, unity-dash, lenses

My music collection is on a separate partition and not under `/home/username/Music`. How do I get the music lens in Unity on Ubuntu 11.10 to search in a different location?

Answer (score 8):

It shows what is inside Banshee's database so you could update this. [How to register downloaded podcast mp3 in Banshee?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41413/how-to-register-downloaded-podcast-mp3-in-banshee)  probably answers how to do that.

You can also `symlink` your music directory. That way anything thinking it should look in `~/Music/` will look in your folder.

You can do that like this:

```
cd /home/username/
mv /home/username/Music /home/username/Music.old
ln -s /your/path/to/music/ Music
```

You can just remove `Music` or `Music.old` if you don't need it.

I assume that rescanning the folder would add them to your database.