# How to change the search location of Unity's Music Lens with Clementine instead of Banshee?

Tags: unity, 11.10, lenses, clementine

I know a similar question was asked by EmyrB [How do you change the search location of the Music Lens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60564/how-do-you-change-the-search-location-of-the-music-lens), but the answer says that the lens uses Banshee, but I don't use Banshee, I use Clementine. Is there a way of getting the lens to actually read the music folder instead of Banshee's database? If not, how hard is it to create a lens to look at your music folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you change the search location of the Music Lens?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60564/how-do-you-change-the-search-location-of-the-music-lens)

Comment: yes, a dupe for sure.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate exactly, but it does point to the same underlying issue.  The current Music Lens only works with Banshee, and there are some users, myself included, who refuse to use Banshee. After all, everyone has their favorite media player.  Considering the openness toward personal choice that Linux provides, it's only right that the Music Lens should not restrict to one player. However, since the focus was on getting the Lens to work properly for 11.10, it's understandable that work on opening up to other players would be held off for later.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to use another player besides banshee with the music lens. In order to have the music lens read from clementine, you would need to write a clementine scope.

Help documentation for this is available at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses#Creating_a_Scope.

There is sample code available at [lp:unity-lens-sample](https://code.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity-lens-sample/trunk), and [lp:unity-lens-music](https://code.launchpad.net/unity-lens-music) is another good place to look.

Comment: Then we should call it Banshee lens instead of Music lens. Why doesn't it work with Rhythmbox or Clementine? Doesn't Zeitgeist simply log that a music file has been opened and then file it away in a separate Lens?

Comment: Lenses are just starting out. I'm sure in time someone will create a lens, or perhap a scope within the current Music Lens, that searches for music using Zeitgeist, or couchdb, or just catalog the Music folder directly.  Give it some time.

Comment: this is valid for 12.04? no way we can change this within the music scope in 12.04 also?

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at: http://shuffleos.com/4224/expand-scope-of-unity-music-lens-to-rhythmbox-clementine-and-guayadeque/

"You can install Rhythmbox, Clementine and Guayadeque scopes in Ubuntu 11.10 by running following commands in the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:markjtully/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clementine-scope guayadeque-scope rhythmbox-scope
```

All of these three scopes functions perfectly with the default Banshee scope of Unity music lens. When you search for a particular song, results from all four scopes are displayed in the music lens."

Logout and login for the changes to take effect.